# Oracle DB emulator

Tags: database, oracle, benchmark, emulator

Don't now if its a right place to ask, so if not please give me a hint. I need some software that do can emulate how Oracle DB works with disks (NOT ORACLE WORKLOAD TOOL). I've already took a look at solutions kinda Benchmark Factory (Quest Software), SwingBench, etc., but they do not emulate. Otherwords I need something like SQL IO but for Oracle.

Thank you for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want Oracle's Orion tool. It is built to mimic Oracle database IO.

From the Orion download page [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-089595.html):

> ORION (Oracle I/O Calibration Tool) is a standalone tool for calibrating the I/O performance for storage systems that are intended to be used for Oracle databases. ... With the goal of closely mimicing the Oracle database, ORION generates a synthetic I/O workload, using the same I/O software stack as Oracle. ORION can be configured to generate a wide range of I/O workloads, including ones that simulate OLTP and data warehouse workloads.

Comment: Oh, I think It'll be OK. Do you have any best practices or something?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long time to reply. I have downloaded and used the tool in a basic fashion. I have seen many blog posts about using Orion but the only whitepaper I have found so far is from Kevin Closson, link to his blog post here: http://kevinclosson.wordpress.com/2006/12/11/a-tip-about-the-orion-io-generator-tool/